# .php won't execute but .html will execute php?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have php 5.3.5 installed however when I try to execute a file with a .php extension I'm prompted to download a file . Now I tried a few solutions but it was redundant since most were just problems with apache config and making sure the module was loaded or adding the type to the apache config. those didnt work so I added the type of .html to the php application type and I can execute html files with php in them but not .php files.. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the correct handler for *.php files:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

See the documentation for details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php